# GraphicsPath using RotateAt drawing with GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

Could someone explain me why code below which is called from Paint event doesn't draw 7 blades (`NumberOfBlades = 7` in this case). For other blade numbers (3-7) it also misses blades for some angles, only for 4 blades it does works. I'm almost sure that it is some kind of small & stupid mistake but i just can't figure it out.

```
Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();
PointF center = new PointF(x2, y);

float angle = 360.0f / (float)pump.Calculations.NumberOfBlades;

for (int i = 0; i < pump.Calculations.NumberOfBlades; i++)
{
    transformMatrix.Reset();
    transformMatrix.RotateAt(angle * i, center);
    blade.Transform(transformMatrix);
    g.DrawPath(blackPen, blade);
}
```

[image: Example]

**Edit**

I've found solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pump.Calculations.NumberOfBlades; i++)
{        
    transformMatrix.RotateAt(angle, center,MatrixOrder.Prepend);
    g.Transform = transformMatrix;
    //lopatka.Transform(transformMatrix);
    g.DrawPath(blackPen, blade);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

So now my question is why it works this way?

Comment: @holtavolt I've tried rotating it incrementally - calling each time rotation with const angle and it was still the same and i'm calling transformMatrix.Reset(); at the beginning of each loop so shouldn't it work?

Comment: @holtavolt ok you are right, pls post your comment as an answer so i could accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're accumulating increasing rotations in your blade GraphicsPath (since you're not resetting blade to the start position each iteration). Either Rotate incrementally, or reset blade to the start position.