GraphicsPath element in List <>
I have defined the class Intersection as:
// ******************************************** class Intersection

public class Intersection
    {
    public  string          name { get; set; }
    public  Color           fill { get; set; }
    public  bool            present { get; set; }
    public  Region          region { get; set; }
    public  GraphicsPath    thick_path { get; set; }
    public  GraphicsPath    thin_path { get; set; }

    public Intersection ( string        Name,
                          Color         Fill,
                          GraphicsPath  Thick_path )
        {
        
        name = Name;
        fill = Fill;
        present = true;
        region = null;
        thick_path = new GraphicsPath ( );
        thick_path = Thick_path;
        
        }
    
    } // class Intersection

and I declare a List of Intersections as:
    List < Intersection >   intersections = 
                                new List < Intersection > ( );

In my application, I add elements to the List with the following method:
    // ********************************* create_intersection_paths
    
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553278/
    //    graphics path-using-rotate-at-drawing-with-gdi
    
    // p0 thru p9 define the north lanes; the east, south, and 
    // west lanes are rotations and translation of the north lanes
    // 
    // there are two sets of rotation and translation: the first 
    // for the roadway and median boundaries (thick_path); the 
    // second for the lane boundaries (thin_path)
    //
    // note that only the outbound lanes are drawn  
    
    void create_intersection_paths ( )

        {
        float           angle = 90.0f;
        Intersection    intersection; 
        GraphicsPath    thick_path = new GraphicsPath ( );
        GraphicsPath    thin_path = new GraphicsPath ( );
        Matrix          transform_matrix = new Matrix ( );
        
        PointF p0 = new PointF ( left_side, top );
        PointF p1 = new PointF ( left_side, bottom );
        PointF p2 = new PointF ( left_side + w, top );
        PointF p3 = new PointF ( left_side + w, bottom );
        PointF p4 = new PointF ( left_side + w2, top );
        PointF p5 = new PointF ( left_side + w2, bottom );
        PointF p6 = new PointF ( graphic_center.X, top );
        PointF p7 = new PointF ( graphic_center.X, bottom );
        PointF p8 = new PointF ( right_side, top );
        PointF p9 = new PointF ( right_side, bottom );
        
        thick_path.StartFigure ( );
        thick_path.AddLine ( p0, p1 );
        thick_path.StartFigure ( );
        thick_path.AddLine ( p6, p7 );
        thick_path.StartFigure ( );
        thick_path.AddLine ( p8, p9 );
        for ( int i = 0; ( i < NUMBER_INTERSECTIONS ); i++ )
            {
            transform_matrix.RotateAt ( angle, 
                                        graphic_center, 
                                        MatrixOrder.Prepend );
            thick_path.Transform ( transform_matrix );
            intersection = new Intersection ( 
                            intersection_index2name [ i ],
                            SystemColors.Window,
                            thick_path );
            intersections.Add ( intersection );
            }
        
        transform_matrix.Reset ( );
        thin_path.StartFigure ( );
        thin_path.AddLine ( p2, p3 );
        thin_path.StartFigure ( );
        thin_path.AddLine ( p4, p5 );
        for ( int i = 0; ( i < NUMBER_INTERSECTIONS ); i++ )
            {
            transform_matrix.RotateAt ( angle, 
                                        graphic_center, 
                                        MatrixOrder.Prepend );
            thin_path.Transform ( transform_matrix );
            intersections [ i ].thin_path = thin_path;
            }

        thick_path.Dispose ( );
        thin_path.Dispose ( );
        transform_matrix.Dispose ( );

        } // create_intersection_paths

When debugging within this method, the thick_paths and thin_paths in each of the instances of intersection are valid. The intersections are painted on the monitor with the following method:
    // ****************************** draw_intersection_background
    
    void draw_intersection_background ( Graphics graphics )
        {
        Pen     thick_pen = new Pen ( Color.Black, 4.0f );
        Pen     thin_pen = new Pen ( Color.Black, 1.0f );
        
        foreach ( Intersection intersection in intersections )
            {
            if ( intersection.present )
                {
                graphics.DrawPath ( thick_pen, 
                                    intersection.thick_path );
                graphics.DrawPath ( thin_pen, 
                                    intersection.thin_path );
                }
            }

        } // draw_intersection_background
        

However, the statement (at line 465)
                graphics.DrawPath ( thick_pen, 
                                    intersection.thick_path );

causes an exception:
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Parameter is not valid."
  Source="System.Drawing"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawPath(Pen pen, GraphicsPath path)
       at DefineIntersection.Define_Intersection.draw_intersection_background(Graphics graphics) in 
           C:\Gustafson\Traffic_Engineering\Synchronization\DefineIntersection\Define_Intersection.cs:line 465
       at DefineIntersection.Define_Intersection.intersection_PB_Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) in 
           C:\Gustafson\Traffic_Engineering\Synchronization\DefineIntersection\Define_Intersection.cs:line 492
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:

intersection.thick_path is invalid.
Thoughts?
Environment:
    Windows 7 Professional (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition
    Microsoft Visual C# 2008
    Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

